# Change from character to POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct, strptime

This should be easy, but now I have tried for an hour, so please help.

I want to change

```
datetime <- "2017-01-18T08:04:18.570Z"
> datetime
[1] "2017-01-18T08:04:18.570Z"
> class(datetime)
[1] "character"
```

to POSIXct. I tried:

```
as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%sZ")
```

but it returns NA. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")#[1] "2017-01-18 08:04:18 IST"`

Comment: Just do `library(anytime)` and `anytime("2017-01-18T08:04:18.570Z")` -- no need for a format.